# When did it become common to have large prisoner exchanges during a war (without a ceasefire etc.)?

Tags: prisoners-of-war

One of the characteristics of the Russia-Ukraine war has been the rather numerous prisoner exchanges that took place (e.g. [1](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/russia-ukraine-war/russia-ukraine-confirm-another-exchange-of-prisoners/2724254) [2](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-russia-prisoner-swap/32255427.html)), even while the fighting is otherwise going on. (I wasn't able to find total numbers for exchanged prisoners though, insofar.)

So, I'm curious if this is the first war in which such exchanges, while the fighting is still going on, have been rather common, or if there were significant precedents in this regard. I think that by WW2 standards or even Vietnam war era they are unusual in terms of frequency (before the fighting stopped that is), but I could be mistaken.

Comment: In ancient times, prisoners were enslaved to the profit of individual soldiers or sometimes the army as a whole, so prisoner exchanges were uncommon. By Medieval times, prisoners were often ransomed -- again, whoever took a prisoner stood to make a profit. This, also, would not encourage mass prisoner exchanges. The mass exchanges I'm aware of involved oaths not to take up arms again against their captors.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @MarkOlson *By Medieval times, prisoners were often ransomed* If they were of noble birth so they had a family or state that could pay for the ransom. Rank and file commoners were more often that not enslaved or just massacred (no sense in wasting your food feeding prisoners).

Comment: I'm sure there were prisoner exchanges during the 'English' Civil Wars. A quick Google search found [this](https://www.civilwarpetitions.ac.uk/blog/prisoners-of-war-the-lowest-priority/) - read the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab%E2%80%93Byzantine_prisoner_exchanges

Comment: In the American Civil War large numbers of war prisoners were "paroled", meaning that they promised to to take up arms again. They were then released and could be looked after by their own side. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parole#Prisoners_of_war

Comment: @DJClayworth: yes, but I haven't read that any of the Russian or Ukrainians exchanged undertook such oaths.

Comment: @Fizz My understanding is that when the paroled prisoners were exchanged they were released from their parole.